# rails update_all for ActiveRecord Relation using 'having' don't work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Sample:

```
a = Model.join("...").where("...").group("...")
b = Model.join("...").where("...").group("...").having("...")
```

If I do:

`a.class` gives me ActiveRecord::Relation. Same with `b.class`.

When I do:

`a.length` i get **1000**. And `b.length` i get **50**

And finally, if i do:

```
a.update_all(field:'...')
=> 1000

b.update_all(field:'...')
=> 1000
```

Not **50**, as I was expecting.

Why this happen? Is there any way to  deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_all` only takes the *constraints* from your query and ignores the `group` and `having` clauses.

Here is the source code of `update_all`

```
def update_all(updates)
    .....
    # HERE IS THE RELEVANT CODE
    # It extracts only the constraints, limit and order clauses. It ignores the rest
    stmt.take(arel.limit)
    stmt.order(*arel.orders)
    stmt.wheres = arel.constraints
    .....
end
```

I guess you would have to do it in two steps, execute your query with the `having` clause and get the list IDs for the 50 records that match and then do an `update_all` on these records using an `IN` clause